# React Native Image Upload to Node Js Mongodb server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, multer-gridfs-storage

Helllo, I am building an app in react-native which submits some images while signing up for the user. The backend is in node js MongoDB and the images are uploaded in MongoDB database handled by gridfs multer storage. The image is captured from react-native-image-picker. I am facing a problem sending images to the server as there's no form element in react-native. I need a little help from any senior react-native developer who can tell me how to send images (base64 encoded) to the server which are handled by gridfs multer storage. I tried using different strategies like formData and stuff. But none of them worked. I searched this problem on google and StackOverflow but none of the solutions worked. Looks like we need to build an open-source package to submit images and documents from react-native
It would be very nice if someone helped me.
Best Regards,
Abdul Bari